# Laravel project deploy

Tags: web-services, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have created a Laravel Project and I tried to upload it to my host which contains **two domain**..

> The first domain is the main domain which contain a working website
>
> The second domain which i want to deploy my Laravel Project in it

Here is the link http://aldar-group.com/public/ it gets me `error 500` I don't know why!

**What I am trying to do:**

is to go to the public folder and be able to see my website normally.

Comment: have you mapped your 2nd domain with the hosting?

Comment: Also can you paste your .htaccess file for the project? Check if the RewriteBase is correct if you are NOT running the second website on a separate subdomain.

Comment: @RaunakGupta i didn't map it no but it is in folder called **aldargroup**..  i mean the second host is in this folder

Comment: @iivannov I am running the laravel project in a second domain that is in folder called **aldargroup**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a shared hosting you're using if yes then :

Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (be aware of don't overwrite the .htaccess file accidentally) then modify your index.php and your bootstrap.php and it will work just fine

Comment: how why there is files and folders that has the same name? i mean it will mix with the first main domain files

Comment: If I am right then your L5 directory's name is aldargroup ? if so then inside this folder put them and I don't think there is any common folders or files except for .htaccess file

Comment: yea I already put all my laravel project in directory's name aldargroup. what i do then?

Comment: modfiy your index.php and your bootstrap.php to add the new location